# MySQL edit values

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, here's an easy one:

I have a table in MySQL where I keep some country names (inserted by the user). The "problem" is that some of the users inserted the country name having no first capital letter.

A need a script (query+PHP) that selects all the values from 1 column inside the table, and apply a PHP script that makes the first letter of every word a capital letter, and the rest in small letter.

Example:
Before edit:

```
Name oNe
cOUNTRY
VaLue
value
```

After edit:

```
Name One
Country
Value
Value
```

I want to know two things:
->easiest way to edit a value inside a mySQL table
->easiest PHP way to capitalize the first letter of every word (space separated) inside a script

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,153518,153562#msg-153562) function:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ICap`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `ICap`(mystring varchar(1000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE myc, pc CHAR(1);
DECLARE myoutstring VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT LOWER(mystring);

WHILE i <= CHAR_LENGTH(mystring) DO
    SET myc = SUBSTRING(mystring, i, 1);
    SET pc = CASE WHEN i = 1 THEN ' ' ELSE SUBSTRING(mystring, i - 1, 1) END;
    IF pc IN (' ', '&', '''', '_', '?', ';', ':', '!', ',', '-', '/', '(', '.') THEN
        SET myoutstring = INSERT(myoutstring, i, 1, UPPER(myc));
    END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN myoutstring;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

After that, you can retrieve results like this:

```
SELECT 
  ICap(name)
FROM
  MyTable
```

or just update all the rows:

```
UPDATE 
  MyTable
SET 
  name = ICap(name)
```

Comment: @Midas: NO, it is just MySQL. You don't need php for your needs. You can achive this only in MySQL.

Comment: And then how do you include this in PHP?

Comment: Actually, I have a problem... In the names there were special characters: ş , â , ă , etc... and they were replaced with ��

Comment: @Midas, you don't include that in PHP, you simply run that using SQL command in phpmyadmin.

Comment: But in PHP this is impossible?

Comment: Yes, you save the text above in a variable, let's name it $query and then you use mysql_query($query) . See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I posted a pure php version below, but + oned this for usage of a function in sql ( though I would never use this ! ). :o)

Comment: @Cristy: Try adding `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` before DROP FUNCTION

Answer (score 3):

To fix the database with only one sql statement use this:

```
UPDATE country_table SET country_name = CONCAT(UCASE(MID(country_name,1,1)),MID(LOWER(country_name),2));
```

This will uppercase the first letter of each country name and lowercase the rest. All without needing any PHP at all.

Comment: This only capitalizes only the first letter of the name, not each first letter, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

->The easiest way to edit a value inside a mySQL table

```
 UPDATE TABLE SET COL="NEW VALUE" where COL="OLD VALUE";
```

Be careful, it will replace all line wher COL is equal to OLd VALUE

->easiest PHP way to capitalize the first letter of every word (space separated) inside a script

There's a function for that : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Answer (score 1):

To Edit the values in in the database just run a Update Query (**I don't know how your table is designed**) from php -- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp.

To Capitalize the first character of every word you can use [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in  mysql if you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(CountryName, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(CountryName FROM 2))) from countries AS properCountryname;
```

The resultset  returned would be your CountryName field with uppercased first letter.

You coud even do the update in one sql query, if you wanted.

If you *really* want php to do the job, something like this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$cnt=0;
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('fakeDB',$con);
$query="SELECT `name`,id FROM countries";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $name= $row["name"];
  $key = $row["id"];
  $field = strtolower($name);
  $array=explode(" ",$name);

  for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
  {
    $array[$i] = ucfirst($array[$i]);
  }
  $field = implode(" ",$array);
  $query2 = "UPDATE countries SET `name`='$name' where id=$key";
  mysql_query($query2);
  $cnt++;
  }
  echo $cnt." Records updated";
?>
```

Just a quick untested thingie but it should give you an idea.